# restarting redis taking long time

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I'm using redis as a broker for celery in my django project. As part of my deployment process I restart the services at the end, so redis, celery, gunicorn (django) etc starting with redis. However I run into an issue where redis will not shutdown.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart redis
$
```

And there it hangs, at time of writing for 15 minutes. `journalctl` shows no entries (logs have rotated overnight I assume), `systemctl status` shows the redis unit as deactivating (sig-term) but no indication what it's doing, other than:

```
May 24 10:31:22 staging systemd[1]: Stopping Advanced key-value store...
May 24 10:31:22 staging run-parts[305]: run-parts: executing /etc/redis/redis-server.pre-down.d/00_example
```

I understand that sig-term allows redis to exit gracefully, so wondered if the celery beat tasks or the django server was accessing it, but having stopped those services it is still hung up. Are there any places I'm not aware of where I can check the status/what it's doing?

edit: Aha, ok so it turns out redis doesn't actually log to systemd by default, instead it logs to `/var/log/redis` which does actually yield some information:

```
31602:M 24 May 10:59:56.097 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
31602:M 24 May 10:59:56.101 * Background saving started by pid 1151
1151:C 24 May 10:59:56.103 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Read-only file system
31602:M 24 May 10:59:56.204 # Background saving error
```

I'm using the defaults for the `dir` and `dbfilename` directives

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump.rdb

# The working directory.
#
# The DB will be written inside this directory, with the filename specified
# above using the 'dbfilename' configuration directive.
#
# The Append Only File will also be created inside this directory.
#
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name.
dir /var/lib/redis

user@server:/var/lib/redis$ ls -l
total 252
-rw-r--r--  1 redis redis 249649 May 23 02:44 dump.rdb
```

It's owned by redis.. why would it be set to read-only?

ok... so

```
user@server:/var/lib/redis$ redis-cli config get dir
1) "dir"
2) "/var/spool/cron"
user@server:/var/lib/redis$ redis-cli config get dbfilename
1) "dbfilename"
2) "root"
```

This is starting to seem very strange. What on earth could have set it to that?

Comment: Why do you think you have restart redis?

Comment: a good point, the reality is I probably don't and it was something I was thinking about changing, it's mostly now about finding out what the issue was

Comment: Redis is writing the entire contents of the cache to disk. Then it has to read the entire cache from disk. Could be reall slow on slow hard drives

Comment: @e4c5 yeah I think this is it, it's trying to write the cache to disk but failing due to a read-only file system error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's starting to look more and more like this was the result of an attack: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3594

The interesting thing is that I was running redis behind a firewall. Currently not sure how the config was changed. Luckily it's a staging server with no sensitive information on it so I can take it down until I work out exactly what the issue was.

Update: So after investigating it further, all I can ascertain is that the attack must have taken place at some point after redis had been installed on the server, but before the firewall was activated. The version of redis I was using binds to 0.0.0.0 by default. I used a deployment script to set the server up so the vulnerability time must have been ~10 seconds. Lesson learned, activate firewall before installing packages.

I will say I dislike redis binding to 0.0.0.0 by default, especially when it has the ability to entirely compromise your server if left exposed. But based on what I've read that argument has been done to death and things have improved in later versions.